# Java Clock too fast

Tags: java, clock

Attempting to make a clock in java in my spare time, having lots of fun and two hours in i am still getting problems with my code.

it tells me the current time but advances way too quickly.

(copy and paste it into an IDE/Compiler and run it and you will see)

Can anyone help a beginner?

```
package clock;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Clock {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int hour;
        int minute;
        int second;
        Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("What hour is it?");
        hour = keyb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What Minute is it?");
        minute = keyb.nextInt();
        second = 0;
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
            int hour;
            int minute;
            int second;
            int turnOn;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                turnOn = 1;
                while (turnOn != 0){
                    System.out.println("Current time is:"+ hour +":"+minute+":"+second);
                    second ++;
                    if (second >= 59){
                        minute ++;
                        second = 0;
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                    if (minute >= 59){
                        hour ++;
                        minute = 0;
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                    if (hour >= 24){
                        hour = 0;
                    }

                }
            }

        }, 0, 1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not use a `boolean` for `turnOn`?

Comment: Hi good idea, just changed it!

Answer (score 1):

You have scheduled your infinite loop to be started every second. `t.schedule(TimerTask, long, long)` starts at 0 properly, but then runs your run method every second. It would be correct if you incremented second in each call of the method `run`. Unfortunately instead of incrementing once, you start infinite loop which increments in every execution.

```
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int hour;
        int minute;
        int second;
        boolean turnOn = true;
        @Override
        public void run() {
//CHANGE HERE!!! \/
//You only want to increment seconds once in a call of run method.
            if (turnOn){
                System.out.println("Current time is:"+ hour +":"+minute+":"+second);
                second ++;
                if (second >= 59){
                    minute ++;
                    second = 0;
                }
                if (minute >= 59){
                    hour ++;
                    minute = 0;
                }
                if (hour >= 24){
                    hour = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }, 0, 1000);
```

Is what you're looking for.

As a side remark please have in mind, that empty `else` blocks are redundant as well as empty lines. You don't need them in your code. What's more it's inappropriate to post them on StackOverflow. Your example should be minimal.

Comment: turnOn = 1?, turnOn is boolean

Comment: @Manish didn't see that. It wasn't the case actually

Answer (score 0):

There are various things to consider:
(1) wait for 1 second after every loop. (ignoring processing time in loop)
(2) put minute and hours logic in 'else if' block.
Something like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Clock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int hour;
        int minute;
        int second;
        Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What hour is it?");
        hour = keyb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What Minute is it?");
        minute = keyb.nextInt();
        second = 0;
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
            int hour;
            int minute;
            int second;
            int turnOn;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                turnOn = 1;
                while (turnOn != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Current time is:" + hour + ":" + minute
                            + ":" + second);
                    second++;
                    if (second >= 59) {
                        minute++;
                        second = 0;
                        if (minute >= 59) {
                            hour++;
                            minute = 0;
                            if (hour >= 24) {
                                hour = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }, 0, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't ' , 0, 1000)' set it to 1 second between every time it does it?

Comment: It does. It's not the point. Check my answer for an explanation.

Comment: Well, run it and see if output says more stronger than comments :)

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed this by changing the turnOn int to 0 after the while loop which will stop the while loop continuing until the next second when it resets it to 1

Comment: Check my answer. You should't run your loop only once everytime. It's not what loops are for.